# Create a Sqlite3 database in a directory other than default

Tags: sqlite

is there a way to create a Sqlite3 database in a directory other than default?

Comment: If using the callable C methods, specify the right directory in your sqlite3_open call.

Comment: Using shell? Check `sqlite3 -help`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to create the folder manually, and then create/open db file in that folder using:

```
sqlite3 ./folderName/databaseName.db
```